# sudo apt-get install eclipse does not install eclipse on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: eclipse

I wanted to install eclipse on ubuntu 14.04 by this command sudo apt-get install eclipse but the install get stopped after 40% or something.. It says it has update or --fix missing problem . So I have used sudo apt-get update several time but even then the install stop and says Unable to fetch some archives.

Comment: You can download it from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: i have download it but I don't know how to install it .

Comment: Please do also `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: I did this but not work . actually I had used earlier ( for other purpose) apt-get install oracle-java7-installer. so now when I install eclipse-installer says version 1.7.0_80 of the JVM is not suitable for this product . version 1.8 or greater is required . Does anyone know which eclipse-installer is suitable for java version 1.7.0_80?

Comment: [Java 1.7 is past its end-of-life](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml) and shouldn't be used anymore.